# Should I use timestamp or separated time columns in large EAV table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have an extremely long table with EAV model.
My columns are tipically ID, Timestamp, Value.
Actually I create an index on ID and Timestamp to increase performance in my queries but it seems to be still slow..
What happend if I split the timestamp in separated integer fields and create an index on those fields? Something like this:
Year(Int), Month(Int), Day(Int), Time(TimeStamp), ID, Value. 
Does it increase performance? 
Today I'm using two kind of db, MySql and PostgreSQL but I have the same doubt for both.

Comment: did you create an index on ID and an inex on timestamp or did you create an index on (ID, timestamp)?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely wrong direction. The new index won't increase performance. Additionally, some of your queries may make you some troubles. Think e.g. about the condition

```
where tstamp between '2015-11-22' and '2016-02-03'
```

and try to write it so it can use the new index(es).

Comment: you're right... the query will become cumbersome but.. what solution could I take to increase performance? create a table per month? Also that solution will over complicate the query... I hear about partitioning but I don't know exactly what it does, should I point in that direction?

Comment: Yes, I think partitioning is the most perspective way in this case. Actually I don't see another meaningful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

(At least in MySQL...)

Do *not* split up a datetime.

Do *not* use partitioning.

Do *not* use multiple tables (one per month / user / etc).

Do think about alternatives to EAV; that model is inherently bad.  (I added a tag; look at other discussions.)

Do use appropriate 'composite' indexes.

Do provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some `SELECTs` so we can help you more specifically.

Do use this pattern for date ranges:

```
WHERE dt >= '2017-02-26'
  AND dt  < '2017-02-26' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Yes, when I query the table I use something like that.. I will check the tag you put in the original post.